# Flutter: How to post JSON array and JSON Object

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to send data to my API URL. How to post below JSON?

for the moment im using http method to call the api but the main issue im facing is to post the json below
any other method or easy way, i can use to call api other than http
The data I want to send is this:

api calling part

```
var url1 = http.get(
        Uri.parse(
            'url'),
        headers: {"Authorization": "access"});
```

```
{
"audio": {},
"output": {
"width": 110,
"height": 110,
"format": "mp4",
"name": "video",
"title": "video",
"description": ""
},
"scenes": [
{
"background": {
"src": [
{
"url": "",
"asset_id": "",
"type": "video",
}
],
"bg_animation": {
"animation": ""
}
},
"time": 7.42,
"keywords": [],
"sub_scenes": [
{
"time": 0.88,
"location": {
"center_x": 360,
"end_y": 1190.3999999999999,
"start_y": 1131.625
},
"text_lines": [
{
"text_animation": [
{
"source": "templates",
"type": "start",
}
],
"text_bg_animation": [
{
"source": "templates",
"type": "start",
}
],
"text": "Six websites. To"
}
],
"subtitle": "",
"font": {
"name": "Helvetica.ttf",
"size": "26",
}
}
],
"sentences": [
{
"time": 0.88,
"text": "Six websites. To"
}
],
"music": false,
"tts": false,
"subtitle": true
}  
],
"projectId":
}
```

Now I have an error about Invalid Argument because I don't know how to send a JSON array.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: could you include your api code too?

Comment: added the api calling part

Comment: go through this https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/send-data to learn  how to send data to server

Answer (score 1):

Create a Map and send it using json.encode(Name of the map)

```
For example Map<dynamic,dynamic> map = new Map();

map = {
   "audio":{
      
   },
   "output":{
      "width":110,
      "height":110,
      "format":"mp4",
      "name":"video",
      "title":"video",
      "description":""
   },
   "scenes":[
      {
         "background":{
            "src":[
               {
                  "url":"",
                  "asset_id":"",
                  "type":"video"
               }
            ],
            "bg_animation":{
               "animation":""
            }
         },
         "time":7.42,
         "keywords":[
            
         ],
         "sub_scenes":[
            {
               "time":0.88,
               "location":{
                  "center_x":360,
                  "end_y":1190.3999999999999,
                  "start_y":1131.625
               },
               "text_lines":[
                  {
                     "text_animation":[
                        {
                           "source":"templates",
                           "type":"start"
                        }
                     ],
                     "text_bg_animation":[
                        {
                           "source":"templates",
                           "type":"start"
                        }
                     ],
                     "text":"Six websites. To"
                  }
               ],
               "subtitle":"",
               "font":{
                  "name":"Helvetica.ttf",
                  "size":"26"
               }
            }
         ],
         "sentences":[
            {
               "time":0.88,
               "text":"Six websites. To"
            }
         ],
         "music":false,
         "tts":false,
         "subtitle":true
      }
   ],
   "projectId":""
}
```

then in you body send it like {"data" : json.encode(map)};

Note: Not the perfect syntax but you will probably get a rough idea.

Comment: thanks for the update i have 1 question how should i pass the data for an array 
for example 
                     "text_animation":[
                        {
                           "source":"templates",
                           "type":"start"
                        },
                         {
                           "source":"templates",
                           "type":"start"
                        }
                        ]

for and array how can i pass multiple objects
should i create a loop or pass array with key?
really appriciate

Comment: @tushar you can store that array in var like` var data = list of array` and in the map you can add it like map = {"text_animation":json.encode(data)} and you can add this map into body and you are good to go

Comment: thanks you once again